# Add upper confidence limit to sgpanel vbar plot in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to add the upper confidence limit on a vertical bar plot in SAS using sgpanel, but can't seem to find a way. If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate any assistance. Many thanks.

```
proc sgpanel data=RG_plot ;
    panelby district species / layout=lattice columns=5 rows=4 ;*novarname ;
    styleattrs datacolors=(lightgray gray) datacontrastcolors=(gray gray);
    refline 2 10  20 50/ axis = y lineattrs=(thickness=1 color=lightgray pattern=dash);
    vbar risk_group /  group=type response=prev datalabel=prev GROUPDISPLAY=CLUSTER DATALABELFITPOLICY=NONE  DATALABELATTRs=(Color=Black Family=Arial Size=6);
    keylegend / title="" down=1 NOBORDER;
run;
```

Comment: Is the limit calculated or based on the data? There are limits options on the VBAR statement (`limits=upper`) or you can switch to vbarparm and specify a variable for the upper limit using `limitupper=variableName`

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/n0anr8vhopccdan1pyccervx6aak.htm

Comment: Many thanks. Looks like vbarparm might be what I need. Appreciate you pointing me in that direction.